# Oracle C++ linux and more weird stuff

Tags: c++, windows, linux, eclipse, oracle

So here is the story. I have this device that uses Linux and more open source tools(btw its an **ARM**). And I was given the task of creating some magic cashier application with it.

I have done it and now my boss have made a new request. He wants me to make that stuff(the device) connect to a remote database(preferably **Oracle**). So thats what I started doing with the light version of oracle instant client. Everything is fine and cool until I ran my first hello world:

```
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;

int main(){
  Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
  Connection *conn = env->createConnection("HR", "password");
  env->terminateConnection(conn);
  Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
  return 0;
}
```

Linking against **occi, clntsh, thread**;
And setting the library search path, along other stuff to: "**${workspace_loc:/OracleTest/instantclient_10_2}**" that is the directory that holds my **.so** files;

Here is the compilation command:

```
ucfront-g++ -Wl,-elf2flt="r" -static -o OracleTest  ./main.o   -locci -lclntsh -lthread -L/usr/local/arm-elf/lib -L"C:\workspace\OracleTest\instantclient_10_2" -L/usr/local/fit-libs/lib
```

And here is the error:

```
/usr/local/arm-elf/bin/ld.real: cannot find -locci collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And there are a few things that I would like to mention:

1- I'm running **windows** and compiling this for **linux**, the instant client version that I've downloaded is for linux x86(No Idea if that will work or if it could be the source of the problem).

2- I'm using a modified version of **eclipse** to develop, specific for that device.

3- I have no idea if I should move those **Oracle** libs to the device after the compilation, so if anyone could give me orientation on that, I would be very thankful.

TLDR: I wan't to compile the above code but it fails to link, help, please!

**EDIT**:

To the two first answers, no I haven't found any specific ARM libraries, I don't think there are any.

Here is the link if anyone can find anything that resemble an ARM distribution I would be thankful.
There are two **RISC** distribution but I don't know if they are compatible with **ARM** :

```
Instant Client for HP-UX PA-RISC (64-bit)
Instant Client for HP-UX PA-RISC (32-bit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have ARM versions of the Oracle library, you're totally out of luck there and would need to get one (perhaps there is a free driver?) or implement the wire protocol manually.

Answer (score 1):

Erm... is there an instant-client (or any Oracle client) for Linux+ARM at all? I don't see one on the downloads page.

If not, you will have to use ODBC, or another database that has an open-source client you can compile.

Answer (score 1):

How about using java with a jdbc-driver ? Oracle-thin-driver is pure-java so it should work on arm. If you cannot write a pure java-app and need to use other libraries on your arm-device, you can use JNI-calls from java to use native-arm libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm pretty sure that you'd need the windows version of the Oracle Client if you're running on a windows machine.

Comment: And how would I make it run in the linux that I'm deploying? Will there be any hard dependencies between the libraries and the compiled software?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to move the `-L` arguments before the `-l` arguments.
2. You'll need ARM libraries to run on the device, not x86 libraries, no idea if Oracle provides those.
3. You probably don't want to have the device directly accessing the database. It would be better to stick a middle-tier server in the stack, and have the devices talk to that (over XML-RPC or other RPC protocol).

Comment: The third option would make my life much easy but, why don't I wan't the devices talking to the database directly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture
Basically it allows independence; allowing both the database and the endpoints to be replaced without requiring the other to change. It avoid precisely the problem you are having - needing proprietary libraries for your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chances are either to use Java and the JDBC driver, as suggested by tjin, or completely forget the idea of directly connecting to the database; create a web service on the server and use that instead.